# Creating a connection and query with vmwarephp

Tags: php, vmware, vcenter

I'm looking at using this PHP library to connect to vcenter hosts and retrieve some data about vms located there:

https://github.com/vadimcomanescu/vmwarephp

This looks like something that could be very useful to me.
However, I’m having trouble connecting to my host.

Using a simple, existing SOAP client request, i can connect to my vhost using:
‘https://top.mydomain.net/sdk’

When trying to connect using this library, I try

```
$vhost = new \Vmwarephp\Vhost(‘top.mydomain.net:443’, ‘username’, ‘password’);
```

Which throws no error.  But if I make any further query to the vhost, for example:

```
$virtualMachines = $vhost->findAllManagedObjects('VirtualMachine', array('configStatus'));  (or anything)
```

I get:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘Vmwarephp\Exception\Soap’ with message ‘ServerFaultCode: type. InvalidRequest: InvalidRequest Object
(
)
‘ in /var/www/smc/lib/vendor/vmwarephp/library/Vmwarephp/Service.php:74
```

Added a bit of debugging to Service.php, but i'm not sure what to do with the response:

```
error is – RetrieveServiceContentArray
(
[_this] => SoapVar Object
(
[enc_type] => 101
[enc_value] => ServiceInstance
[enc_stype] => ServiceInstance
)

)
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘Vmwarephp\Exception\Soap’ with message ‘ServerFaultCode: type. InvalidRequest: InvalidRequest Object
```

Any suggestions? I’m connecting to a vCenter server running 5.5

Comment: Figured out my connection question, but the error still remains when querying the vhost with any query.